# how to calculate mdape in R

Tags: r, time-series, metrics

I want to use mdape() function to get median absolute percentage error in R, but it says :

```
could not find function "mdape"
```

I use Metrics library, and it works for median absolute error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there exists `mdape` function in `Metrics` package.

I found `cognitiveutils::MDAPE()` and `prophet::performance_metrics(df, metrics = 'mdape', rolling_window = 0.1)`

Try([cognitiveutils](https://rdrr.io/github/JanaJarecki/cognitiveutils/man/MDAPE.html))

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("JanaJarecki/cognitiveutils")
cognitiveutils::MDAPE()
```

or([prophet](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/prophet/versions/1.0/topics/performance_metrics))

```
install.packages("prophet")
prophet::performance_metrics(df, metrics = 'mdape', rolling_window = 0.1)
```